# How to Open Activity using getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, android-context, android-bottomnav

I'm using a bottom navigation menu, on each `itemMenu` i'm calling a function to open the correct Activity:

```
//In the  activty "A" where there's the bottom nav bar:

HelpActivity help = new HelpActivity();

                case R.id.navigation_home:
                help.openHomeActivity();
```

In the `HelpActivity`

```
public void openHomeActivity(){

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

The app crashes, how to solve this, please?

the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: App crashes then what is error inside logcat ??? Post it here. And also check inside manifest you declared *HomeActivity* or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HelpActivity help = new HelpActivity();
```

**Never** create an instance of an activity yourself.

Modify `openHomeActivity()` to be:

```
public void openHomeActivity(Context context){

    Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then, when you call it, pass in *an already existing `Context`*, such as the `Activity` that has your bottom navigation view.

Comment: But how to call the openHomeActivity()?

Comment: @Machine: Put `openHomeActivity()` on the class where the `switch` block with the `case R.id.navigation_home` stuff is. Or, get rid of the method and just call `startActivity()` from inside the `case R.id.navigation_home` block.

Comment: I did not know we could call the startActivity() away from the intent, now i can use a classHelp, Thank you so much for your help and time

Comment: `openHomeActivity(this);`